# Sticky Layout and Scroll Down

Tags: android, android-layout

i am implementing Sticky Layout inside scroll View, The search Bar Sticks nicely but i need to scroll down search bar and invite button anywhere from scroll View, Currently searchbar sticks at top but it does not scroll down from any position i have to scroll to top. I want functionality like google Play Store Search Panel, if i scroll up the search bar sticks and top and when i scroll down then i can see search bar and Invite button as well, my code

```
               <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/gray_bg">



    <com.mtg.workapp_v2.listing.CommonViews.StickyScrollView
        android:id="@+id/stickyScrollView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/btnInviteFromPhoneContacts"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:background="@color/white"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="true">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textInviteFromPhoneContacts"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:text="@string/id_invite_from_phone_contacts"
                android:textAllCaps="true"
                android:textColor="@color/row_trash_bg"
                android:textSize="15dp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="11dp"
                android:layout_height="11dp"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
                android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/textInviteFromPhoneContacts"
                android:contentDescription="@null"
                android:src="@drawable/expand_icon_v2" />
        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/layoutSearch"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="45dp"
            android:tag="sticky"
            android:background="@android:color/white"
            android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
            android:visibility="visible">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:background="@drawable/search_bar_bg">

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/editSearch"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/imgSearch"
                    android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/imageNext"
                    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                    android:gravity="start|center_vertical"
                    android:hint="@string/id_search_messages"
                    android:singleLine="true"
                    android:text=""
                    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                    android:textColorHint="@color/text_gray_color"
                    android:textSize="15dp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/imageNext"
                    android:layout_width="30dp"
                    android:layout_height="30dp"
                    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
                    android:contentDescription="@null"
                    android:padding="3dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/right_arrow" />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/imgSearch"
                    android:layout_width="30dp"
                    android:layout_height="30dp"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
                    android:contentDescription="@null"
                    android:padding="3dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/search_icon_grey" />
            </RelativeLayout>
        </RelativeLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/newMessageRecycleView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"

            android:focusable="false" />

        <ScrollView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginTop="2dp"

            android:visibility="gone"
            >

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:id="@+id/btnSelectExistingWorkAppGroups"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="50dp"
                    android:background="@color/white">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/textSelectExistingWorkAppGroup"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                        android:text="@string/id_select_workapp_group"
                        android:textAllCaps="true"
                        android:textColor="@color/row_trash_bg"
                        android:textSize="15dp"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />
                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/imgSelectGroups"
                        android:layout_width="20dp"
                        android:layout_height="20dp"
                        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                        android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
                        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                        android:contentDescription="@null"
                        android:src="@drawable/expand" />

                    <View
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="2dp"
                        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                        android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
                        android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
                        android:background="@color/gray_bg" />

                </RelativeLayout>

                <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                    android:id="@+id/recyclerExistingWorkAppGroups"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"

                    android:focusable="false" />

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:id="@+id/btnSelectExistingWorAppContacts"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="50dp"
                    android:background="@color/white">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/textSelectExistingWorkAppContacs"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                        android:text="@string/id_select_workapp_contacts"
                        android:textAllCaps="true"
                        android:textColor="@color/row_trash_bg"
                        android:textSize="15dp"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />
                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/imgSelectContacts"
                        android:layout_width="20dp"
                        android:layout_height="20dp"
                        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                        android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
                        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                        android:contentDescription="@null"
                        android:src="@drawable/expand" />
                    <View
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="2dp"
                        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                        android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
                        android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
                        android:background="@color/gray_bg" />

                </RelativeLayout>



                <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                    android:id="@+id/recyclerExistingWorkAppContacts"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                    android:focusable="false" />

            </LinearLayout>
        </ScrollView>

    </LinearLayout>
    </com.mtg.workapp_v2.listing.CommonViews.StickyScrollView>

</RelativeLayout>
```